# Solving Second Order differential equation using particular Integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I faced a problem while solving a second order differential equation using particular integral. Please help me with this problem.

($D^2+1)$y=$x^2$sin2x

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the wording of the question is very succinct, the answer will be succinct too.
$$y''+y=x^2\sin(2x) \tag 1$$
First, solve the associated homogeneous OPDE $y''+y=0 \tag 2$
Second, search a particular solution of (1) on the form $\quad p_1(x)\sin(2x)+p_2(x)\cos(2x)\quad$ with unknowns $p_1(x)$ and $p_2(x)$.

Third, add a particular solution of (1) to the general solution of (2).

HINT : Try very simple polynomials for $p_1$ and $p_2$.

Comment: we can solve this using the concept of differential equations with constant co-efficients where we find C.F (complementary function) and P.I (Particular integral). But if this could be solved with variation of parameter, is there any need we should try any other method? Does variation of method has any limitations ?